# Qt5 build/debug project not update/ no changed

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

i'm very happy with Qt5.8. but, sometime when i'm compile or run a project in QtCreator, compile output show like this:

> C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ../Pou/Pou.pro
>   C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ../Pou/Pou.pro
>   C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ../Pou/Pou.pro
>   C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ../Pou/Pou.pro
>   C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ../Pou/Pou.pro
>   C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ../Pou/Pou.pro
>   C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ../Pou/Pou.pro
>   C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ../Pou/Pou.pro
>   C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ../Pou/Pou.pro
>   C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ../Pou/Pou.pro
>   C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ../Pou/Pou.pro
>   C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ../Pou/Pou.pro

**sometimes** it happens. to solve this problem, i copy paste all source(text, not file) manually to a new project. i think its ugly solution. how to solve this problem without manually copy paste the source?

detil of my environment:
- My OS: Windows10
- Qt Creator version: 3.6.1
- Compiler: MinGW

Answer (score 0):

i have solve my problem. just open all file, and save it. it's about date modified of files. i have changed the date of my pc before compiling.